# Scala , Spark code : Iterating over array and evaluating expression using an element in the array

Tags: apache-spark

I am coding in scala-spark  and trying  to segregate all strings and column datatypes . 
I am getting the output for columns(2)_2 albeit with a warning but when i apply the same thing in the if statement i get an error . Any idea why. This part got solved by adding columns(2)._2 : David Griffin

```
var df = some dataframe
var columns = df.dtypes
var colnames = df.columns.size

var stringColumns:Array[(String,String)] = null;
var doubleColumns:Array[(String,String)] = null;
var otherColumns:Array [(String,String)] = null;

columns(2)._2
columns(2)._1

for (x<-1 to colnames)
{ 
    if (columns(x)._2 == "StringType")
     {stringColumns = stringColumns ++  Seq((columns(x)))}

    if (columns(x)._2 == "DoubleType")
     {doubleColumns = doubleColumns ++  Seq((columns(x)))}

    else
     {otherColumns = otherColumns ++ Seq((columns(x)))}
}
```

Previous Output:

```
stringColumns: Array[(String, String)] = null
doubleColumns: Array[(String, String)] = null
otherColumns: Array[(String, String)] = null
res158: String = DoubleType
<console>:127: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String)
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
                  {stringColumns = stringColumns ++ columns(x)}
```

Current Output:

```
stringColumns: Array[(String, String)] = null
doubleColumns: Array[(String, String)] = null
otherColumns: Array[(String, String)] = null
res382: String = DoubleType
res383: String = CVB
java.lang.NullPointerException


                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing a `.`. Change this:

```
columns(2)_2
```

to

```
columns(2)._2
```

If nothing else, it will get rid of the warning.

And then, you need to do:

```
++ Seq(columns(x))
```

Here's a cleaner example:

```
scala> val arr = Array[(String,String)]()
arr: Array[(String, String)] = Array()

scala> arr ++ (("foo", "bar"))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String)
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
          arr ++ (("foo", "bar"))

scala> arr ++  Seq(("foo", "bar"))
res2: Array[(String, String)] = Array((foo,bar))
```

Comment: Thanks got rid of the warning

Comment: Did you try changing `columns(x)_2` to `columns(x)._2` ?

Comment: Edited my answer -- ++ requires you wrap the right hand side in a `Seq(...)`

Comment: Hmmm.... i must be doing something wrong then . I am getting null pointer exception error i directly added  Seq(("Foo","bar")) to the logic and i got the same error . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer modified from David Griffins answer so please up-vote him too . Just altered ++ to +:=

```
var columns = df.dtypes
var colnames = df.columns.size

var stringColumns= Array[(String,String)]();
var doubleColumns= Array[(String,String)]();
var otherColumns= Array[(String,String)]();


for (x<-0 to colnames-1)
{ 
    if (columns(x)._2 == "StringType"){
        stringColumns +:= columns(x)
    }else if (columns(x)._2 == "DoubleType") {
        doubleColumns +:= columns(x)
    }else {
        otherColumns +:= columns(x)
     }
}
println(stringColumns)
println(doubleColumns)
println(otherColumns)
```